# Load More Pagination in HTML Web Scraping

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination

I want to scrape all the article links (approximately 1,190,527 in total) from this URL, [Prothom Alo](https://www.prothomalo.com/search). However, there's no pagination that changes the URL with each click. Instead, there's only a 'load more' button that doesn't alter the URL or the script when clicked. How can I automate the process of scraping the entire page using BeautifulSoup in Python? Here is the inspect  code of load more:

```
<div class="more _7ZpjE"><span class="load-more-content _7QoIj">আরও</span></div>
```

here is the inspect code of each article links:

```
<a target="_self" aria-label="" class="card-with-image-zoom" href="https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/district/mxdzzh4ak5">
```

I attempted to use Selenium, but after scraping 10,000 articles, it shows an error that, the 'load more' button no longer appears or something like that. Here's the Selenium code I've used:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

url = "https://www.prothomalo.com/search"

driver.get(url)

count = 1


def load_more_articles():
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "google_ads_iframe_85406138/News_Int_660x440_0")))

        load_more_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "load-more-content")

        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", load_more_button)

        load_more_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)  
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error loading more articles:", str(e))
        return False


with open("prothomalo.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    visited_links = set()

    while True:
        page_source = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")

        article_links = soup.find_all("a", class_="card-with-image-zoom")
        for link in article_links:
            article_url = link.get("href")
            if article_url not in visited_links:
                file.write(article_url + "\n")
                visited_links.add(article_url)
                print(f"{count} is written")
                count += 1

        if not load_more_articles():
            break

driver.quit()
```

Comment: You can't do that. Your site doesn't allow output with offset more than 9999 articles. It returns server error 403 `{"error":{"message":"Result window is too large, limit + offset must be less than or equal to [10000] but was [10015]"}}`